# How can I increase the efficiency of my loop that replaces values?

Tags: pandas, performance

```
def assignGroup(row):
    if row['democ_bad']== 1:
        return 4
    elif row['democ_bad'] == 2:
        return 3
    elif row['democ_bad'] == 3:
        return 2
    elif row['democ_bad'] == 4:
        return 1
    else:
        return np.nan

wvs['demo_better']=wvs.apply(assignGroup,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
mapping = {1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1}
wvs['demo_better'] = wvs['democ_bad'].map(mapping)
```

It should return nans when there is no mapping.

Comment: However, this code only provides one value for my variable whereas the first code reveals different result.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "only provides one value" and "different result".  Can you provide example data for `wvs` and show what it should look like after?

Comment: Apparently, the variable was not created according to the code book. It worked well in the end. Many thanks!